# Autocomplete does not appear to 'take'

Tags: xpages

I have a registration form that I'm trying to prevent the fields from getting auto populated.  When the user logs in, I populate their name and email address from our internal database.  Once that's done, they complete another bunch of fields like phone number, address, etc.  When you put the cursor in, say, the phone field, some suggestions are displayed.  If you pick one, the name and email address are overwritten.  I have set the autocomplete to false on all these fields but the suggestions still appear when you put the cursor in those fields.  I checked the html and it is in fact set to false:

```
<input type="tel" id="view:_id1:_id45:PhoneNumber" name="view:_id1:_id45:PhoneNumber" autocomplete="off" class="formInputText required">
```

I found a suggestion of using

```
<xp:form autocomplete="off">
```

But that didn't work either.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the autocomplete feature.

thanks
clem

Comment: autocomplete is a mystery : https://stackoverflow.com/q/2530/785061

Comment: I've tried setting autocomplete to other text and had some success, but seems hit and miss as the browsers decide that we developers don't need this control.  Try autocomplete="nope"

Comment: 'Nope', it didn't work. ;-)  But thanks.  I am opening a PMR.  Will post the answer if I get one.